# Why I can't allocates (dynamic by malloc) variables outside function?

Tags: c

Can someone explain me why I can't do something like that?

```
int* arr1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
static int* arr2 = malloc(sizeof(int));

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

What is the reason that I get in this case compilation error?

> initializer element is not constant

Comment: Just search Global Pointer in C, you will get many posts on StackOverflow, already explaining it. Don't shower any more duplicates, please.

Comment: @AbhishekJaiswal Well, your proposed duplicate has nothing to do with the question presented here.

Answer (score 8):

Because malloc is a function (which returns a pointer to the allocated area) and in C you are only allowed to run code (call functions, do calculations, etc) inside a "running sequence", that's why C is a procedural language.

this is different from setting a static initial value to the variable, which will be initialized by the c runtime init before calling main()

Answer (score 1):

Objects defined at file scope have static storage duration.

From C Standard#6.7.9p4 [Initialization]

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration shall be **constant expressions or string literals**. *[emphasis mine]*